# Is Apple IOS RDP possible

Tags: remote-desktop, ios

Will RDP work on Apple devices? I just learned about RDP and it only seems related to windows . I have not tried on an apple device because I’m just learning about this

Comment: as a client or a server? RDP is a protocol and there's clients or servers not on windows, like xrdp on linux that work reasonably well

Comment: iOS does not have an RDP or VNC/RFB server built in, and the iOS app sandboxing that's in place for security and privacy reasons prevents an app from having access to the screen output of other apps, so it's not possible to create an App Store app that could do this. If you want an iOS device to control a Windows box via RDP, that seems possible and there are probably apps for that. But iOS devices cannot be remotely operated by RDP, VNC, or any other screen sharing or remote desktop protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Microsoft's RDP for [macOS](https://apps.apple.com/na/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id714464092) & [iOS](https://apps.apple.com/na/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id714464092) [freeware] - from which you can remote into Windows machines. You can't do it the other way round, neither macOS nor iOS will respond to MS RDP, but macOS has its own [Screen Sharing](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mh14066/mac) app included in the OS or can use the more elaborate [Apple Remote Desktop](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/remote-desktop/welcome/mac) [$80] & will respond also as a generic [VNC](https://support.apple.com/guide/remote-desktop/apdbed09830/mac) client.

You can remote into iOS using the new Switch Control, but this is something I'm not personally familiar with - there's a guide at https://www.helpwire.app/blog/remote-control-iphone/